# LinkedList out of bounds exception

Tags: java, linked-list, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to make an implementation of Tom Nichols' low pass filter.
My approach was like this, but I get an out of bounds exception all the time even though I've guarded against it:

```
private float  filterValue(LinkedList<Float> listOfItems)
    {
        final float ALPHA = 0.2f;
        float filtered;

        int marker = listOfItems.size();

        if (listOfItems.size()>2)
             marker = listOfItems.size() - 1;

        float current = listOfItems.pollLast();
        float previous = listOfItems.get(marker); <<-- line 282

        filtered = (float) previous + ALPHA*(current - previous);

        return filtered;


    }
```

error log:

```
12-16 15:54:51.148: E/AndroidRuntime(2055): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-16 15:54:51.148: E/AndroidRuntime(2055): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
12-16 15:54:51.148: E/AndroidRuntime(2055):     at      java.util.LinkedList.get(LinkedList.java:519)
 12-16 15:54:51.148: E/AndroidRuntime(2055):    at se.macke.velocitysensor.SensorActivity$MySensorEventListener.filterValue(SensorActivity.java:282)
 12-16 15:54:51.148: E/AndroidRuntime(2055):    at se.macke.velocitysensor.SensorActivity$MySensorEventListener.getAccelerometer(SensorActivity.java:249)
12-16 15:54:51.148: E/AndroidRuntime(2055):     at se.macke.velocitysensor.SensorActivity$MySensorEventListener.onSensorChanged(SensorActivity.java:231)
12-16 15:54:51.148: E/AndroidRuntime(2055):     at android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$ListenerDelegate$1.handleMessage(SystemSensorManager.java:204)
12-16 15:54:51.148: E/AndroidRuntime(2055):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
```

Suggestions, please.

/M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Size returns the actual size of the list, it is not zero indexed.  The get method retrieves an item from the list which uses a zero based index.  The guard condition does not prevent this issue.

```
int marker = listOfItems.size();  //assume size = 3,
if (listOfItems.size()<2)   //condition is not met.
    marker = listOfItems.size() - 1;

float previous = listOfItems.get(marker); //attempts to access non-existent index of 3
```

**Fix**

```
private float  filterValue(LinkedList<Float> listOfItems)
{
    final float ALPHA = 0.2f;
    float filtered;

    int marker = listOfItems.size();

    if (listOfItems.size() > 0){

        marker = listOfItems.size() - 1;

        float current = listOfItems.pollLast();
        float previous = listOfItems.get(marker); <<-- line 282

        filtered = (float) previous + ALPHA*(current - previous);
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

Comment: Man, I thought I tried just about that already.. Only I had if (listOfItems.size() >=2 ). Seems to have done the trick any way, I'm getting slightly less strange results. ^^Thx alot!

Answer (score 3):

```
if (listOfItems.size()<2)
    marker = listOfItems.size() - 1;
```

What if `listOfItems.size()` is zero then var `marker` would be -1 which cause `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

you should put lower bound `> 0`.

```
if (listOfItems.size()>0 && listOfItems.size()<2)
    marker = listOfItems.size() - 1;
```